# Explain This Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Could anyone explain this query?

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN 
                 REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)+2,111),'/','')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN 
                 REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)+1,111),'/','')
        ELSE 
             REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0),111),'/','')
        END
AS RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange
```

The result is RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange20150501. What I really do not understand is what part of the query is writing the date, '20150501'?

Thanks

Comment: What I do not understand is how it is getting 20150501 when that is not today's date

Answer (score 0):

The DATEADD with the ,0) is doing this.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Saturday'
            THEN 
                 REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)+2,111),'/','')
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateadd(mm, DATEDIFF(MM, 0, getdate()), 0)) = 'Sunday'
            THEN 
                 REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)+1,111),'/','')
        ELSE 
             REPLACE('RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0),111),'/','')
        END
AS RXRatingsTrialV3DailyChange,
getdate()m,
DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),
DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)
```